# Insert Multiple Where in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
SELECT AccessName
from Accesses
where IsValid = 1 and AccessID = 1
```

I want to convert this to a Linq query. I tried the following query but it is not working

```
List<Access> Accesses = _context.Accesses.ToList();

var query = from acc in Accesses
            where acc.IsValid = 1 && 
                  acc.AccessID = v
            select acc.A
```

I am having trouble near the && operator

Comment: What is the meaning "not working" ? Did you get error ?

Answer (score 4):

For equality you need to do: `==` not `=`
For more details please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons#value-equality

```
List<Access> Accesses = _context.Accesses.ToList();
    
var query = from acc in Accesses
            where acc.IsValid == 1 && 
                  acc.AccessID == 1
            select acc.AccessName
```

Also I don't know what `v` is meant to be, variable or some value - I've changed that to 1, as per your original query, likewise `acc.A` I assumed it should be `acc.AccessName`.

Comment: Note that we generally close questions like this as typos rather than answering them.

Comment: Thank you This is working not and Yes v is a variable and acc.A is acc.AccessName sorry about that @DavidG